# Commas in either/or sentences in the imperative mood

Tags: grammar, commas, imperatives, correlative-conjunctions

I'm working on a card game. I often come across the need to join two imperative statements with the correlative conjunction "either / or", like so:

> Either discard a card, or draw a card from your deck.

But I'm never sure if that comma is supposed to be there or not.

These sentences can sometimes get quite complex, and it feels like the comma adds clarity:

> Either switch a card in your hand with one in the discard pile that has the same suit, or discard cards from the top of your deck until a face card is discarded.

From my research on a few different grammar sites, it sounds like you generally do not use a comma with either / or... but some sites provide the addendum that sometimes you do when you're joining two independent clauses. I wonder if my use of the imperative mood complicates this case further.

Is there a single rule that governs comma usage when joining two independent imperative clauses with either / or? Is the comma in these cases *required*, *optional*, or *discouraged*?

Comment: Do you pronounce these aloud with an intonation pattern signalling what would be a comma when written?

Comment: Honestly I think I can pronounce them either way. I think I tend to pause more consistently for the second example than the first.

Comment: Commas don't have many hard and fast rules -- you get to decide this. / Look at Dominion.  It uses a more succinct style: Discard a card or draw a card.  (It's understood that it would be drawn from the player's deck.)  Replace a card with a discarded card of the same suit, or discard cards from your deck until a face card has been discarded.

Comment: A shorter sentence (either take a bus or call a cab) may be best without a comma; in a longer one, a comma may help the reader distinguish the two options.

Comment: @Xanne ... and, if reading aloud, not be forced to pause for breath at an unbidden site.